# Custom transition

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation controller, and inside of that navigation controller I have a home screen, from the home screen I click a button which goes to another screen.

But the standard show animation when using a navigation controller is that it slides from the side, but what I want to do is that the view controller slides up from bottom of the screen and creates a sort of bouncing animation when it reaches the top.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code you're trying to use, and explain where you're having trouble. If you haven't tried anything yet, jump over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `uinavigationcontroller custom transition` ... you will find plenty of examples, discussions, tutorials, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who wanted to use custom transition two things to remember `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocols. Now conform `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` inside your customclass inheriting from `NSObject`

```
import UIKit
class CustomPushAnimation: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.2
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerVw = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
        guard let fromVc = fromViewController, let toVc = toViewController else { return }
        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVc)

     //For different animation you can play around this line by changing frame
        toVc.view.frame = finalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: finalFrame.size.height/2)
        containerVw.addSubview(toVc.view)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toVc.view.frame = finalFrame
            fromVc.view.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion: {(finished) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
            fromVc.view.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

> The above method will take care of the animation. After that create
>   the above object and use inside yourViewController class

```
import UIKit
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
lazy var customPushAnimation: CustomPushAnimation = {
        return CustomPushAnimation()
    }()
func openViewControler() {
}let vc =//Assuming your view controller which you want to open
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
//Set transitioningDelegate to invoke protocol method
 navigationController.transitioningDelegate = self
present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> Note: In order to see the animation. Never set animation flag to false
>   while presenting the ViewController. Otherwise your animation will
>   never work.

Lastly implement the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol method inside `YourViewcontroller` class

```
extension YourViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return customPushAnimation
    }
```

> Whenever you present the viewcontroller above protocol method will
>   called and your animation magic will appear.